# How can I make an HTTPS POST request in node.js?

Tags: node.js, post, https, request

How can I make an HTTPS POST request to an API. My code doesn't work, because it cannot find the resource.

API Documentation: https://applymagicsauce.com/documentation at Authentication

My code, which doesn't work

```
var https = require('https');

var options = {
  host: 'https://api.applymagicsauce.com',
  port: 443,
  path: '/auth',
  method: 'POST'
};

var req = https.request(options, function(res) {
  console.log('STATUS: ' + res.statusCode);
  console.log('HEADERS: ' + JSON.stringify(res.headers));
  res.setEncoding('utf8');
  res.on('data', function (chunk) {
    console.log('BODY: ' + chunk);
  });
});

req.on('error', function(e) {
  console.log('problem with request: ' + e.message);
});

// write data to request body
req.write('data\n');
req.write('data\n');
req.end();
```

error message: `STATUS: 415
HEADERS: {"server":"nginx/1.15.10","date":"Fri, 09 Aug 2019 18:22:48 GMT","content-type":"application/json;charset=UTF-8","transfer-encoding":"chunked","connection":"close","x-content-type-options":"nosniff","x-xss-protection":"1; mode=block","cache-control":"no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate","pragma":"no-cache","expires":"0","strict-transport-security":"max-age=15724800; includeSubDomains","x-frame-options":"DENY"}
BODY: {"timestamp":"2019-08-09T18:22:48.981+0000","status":415,"error":"Unsupported Media Type","message":"Content type 'application/octet-stream' not supported","path":"/auth"}`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your host includes a path, but you're also providing a path.

Comment: yes I've tried it now without and it works but I get an error message too:

Comment: try removing the schema from host, eg. www.google.com vs "https:// www.google.com"